# Kafka commit failed due to unsuccessful group coordinator rediscovery

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an issue with the commit in one of my services. It uses `consumer.assign`, not `subscribe`. After processing messages it commits offsets in kafka using `commitAsync`. Sometimes (one in a few days) commit failed with a `RetriableCommitFailedException` and in logs I see messages like this:

```
[Consumer clientId=my-client-id, groupId=my-group-id] Offset commit failed on partition my-topic-28 at offset 283259051: The request timed out.
[Consumer clientId=my-client-id, groupId=my-group-id] Group coordinator 10.54.116.10:9093 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: error response REQUEST_TIMED_OUT.isDisconnected: false. Rediscovery will be attempted.
```

For some reason sometimes this rediscovery has no effect and after 10 minutes of retrying commit is still failing.

At first, I thought that this is somehow related to the fact that I'm using `assign`, not `subscribe`. And I somehow receive rebalance that I don't handle properly. But according to the javadocs `ConsumerRebalanceListener` is not working with the `assign`, so the problem itself not with the rebalance.

Also, admins said that all kafka nodes was fine when I received an error, and partition leader was not changing.

At the current moment, I have no clue in what direction should I move? Why commit fail even after 10 minutes of retrying? Why group coordinator rediscovery failed sometimes?

I'm using java client 2.8.0, broker version is 2.3.1.